# How to sent JSON request in the Post method in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, json, web-services, request

I am using the JSON string as a request to the server and get the response in the JSON format. I have used this code for posting the data,

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"id\":\"1\"}}"];
NSLog(@"the request string is %@", requestString);
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http//www.aaaa.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[theConnection start];

if( theConnection ){            
    receiveData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

In server side, they have used core PHP with post method, whenever i sent the request to the server, i am not getting the data and JSON request file doesn't reached to the server. So please help me out.

But the above code is perfectly working fine in the another project and they have used SOAP in the server side. So please suggest me, where can i change the code to achieve this, in server side or iPhone side.

Thanks!

Comment: The URL you specify looks wrong, @"http:aaaa.com", but I assume you have "http://" in your actual code.  Other than that, I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Are there any clues in your webserver's error long?

Comment: @ Snips, I have used the proper formats of URL and it doesn't work and Any other Clue?.

Comment: Still it 's not a proper URL. It has to be `@"http://www.aaaa.com"`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Snips comment,

Please add the following header also.

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Also , in this line,

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"id\":\"1\"}}"];
```

it has 2 close braces. Please check it.

**Update:**

Have you implemented the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods?

Please refer the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already used that header, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

hi please add the below line to your code..... may be it will help you

> [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

- create post parameter with there require values.
- implement NSURLConnectionDelegate delegate in your .h file.

  ```
        url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"#####called url ####### change this according your need ####"];
          post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&tags=%@&location=%@&location_lat=%f&location_lng=%f&pluses=%@&minuses=%@&image=%@&creator=%@",self.txtName.text,tags,self.txtLocation.text,center.latitude,center.longitude,plusValu,minusValu,imgUrlStr,deviceId];

       NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

      NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];


      NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

      [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
      [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

      [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
      [request setHTTPBody:postData];
      NSURLConnection *connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

      if(connection){
          resData = [NSMutableData data];

      }
  ```

  implement delegate method and get data from server

  ```
    (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
     NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse %s##### response  %@",__FUNCTION__,response);
   //[resData setLength:0];
    }

   (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
     {
     NSLog(@"didReceiveData %@",[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] JSONValue]);

    }

     (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
        {
       //NSLog(@"didFailWithError %s and Error %@",__FUNCTION__,[error userInfo]);
     //[responseData release];
      // [_delegate parserDidFailedWithError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed:  %@",   [error description]] forAction:_action];
      }

   (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  {

     //   NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading %s",__FUNCTION__);

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need the following:

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = @{@"id": @"1"};
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http//www.aaaa.com"]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if ( theConnection ) {            
    receiveData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```