# Communication with a web server

Tags: ios, json, webserver, client-server, communication

I am working on an application for iOS which needs to synchronize data between multiple users and one web server.
I did some research and the best solution I found for this is working with JSON.
At the moment I have a .json file on a web server and I am able to download the data to my iphone app and parse it.
I have two problems I didn't manage to understand yet:
1. How can each iphone user write back data to the json file on the server?
2. How can I take a data table and automaticly convert it to a .json file? so the .json file on the server will be updated every few minutes or so...

I'll appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Do you mean to read/write to an SQL DB?

Comment: no... only if I wont manage to do it with JSON alone

Answer (score 0):

You dont send JSON file as afile to the devices, you send a JSON request, I advice to do **more reading** about this topic, you can start from below:

[Working with JSON in iOS 5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

[enter link description How to make HTTP request from iPhone and parse JSON result](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/how-to-make-http-request-from-iphone-and-parse-json-result/)

[How to fetch and parse JSON by using data models](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/)

and read this SO question:

[iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

[How to sent JSON request in the Post method in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181965/how-to-sent-json-request-in-the-post-method-in-iphone)

[How to send json data in the Http request using NSURLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456966/how-to-send-json-data-in-the-http-request-using-nsurlrequest)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I already visited all this websites. My problem is not the fetching or the parsing. My problem is how to send data back to the server. I want the json file to include how many times users "liked" a certain data object.

Comment: Ok but you can send the JSON to your server as a POST, and take it in your backend as a JSON response (maybe using jQuery) but not as a JSON physical file, are we at the same track or I didn't get you? coz I am using JSON and PHP backend in most of my apps.

Comment: I think the post message is what I need. i'll check out more about it.